# Broadcasting flag but receiving null

Tags: android

Trying to Broadcast flag, but while receiving I am getting "null". Can someone guide me. Below is my sender and receiver code.

Sending :

```
Intent sendableIntent = new Intent("abc");
sendableIntent.putExtra("kicked", prefs.getSurveySubmittedStatus(context));
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AcrService.this).sendBroadcast(sendableIntent;
Log.d("TAG", "SDK : Broadcast Send is : " + prefs.getSurveySubmittedStatus(context));
```

Receiving :

```
protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            Log.d("TAG", "Inside onResume");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("abc"));
        }

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("kicked");
            Log.d("TAG", "Received Broadcast : " + message);
            //Getting null here, whereas I should receive "true or false"
          }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);

    }
```

Comment: what does `prefs.getSurveySubmittedStatus(context)` return? is it a `String`? if so, what is the value?

Comment: No it is boolean, will return "true" or "false".

Comment: so what `getStringExtra` is for?

Comment: so would that not return me boolean as String?

Comment: if you are using `putExtra(String, boolean)` what `get*Extra` you should use? just see `Intent#get*Extra` documentation

Comment: ok got it, I made it : Boolean message = intent.getBooleanExtra("kicked", false);

Comment: just `boolean message`, no need for `Boolean message`